# How partitions are created in spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I am reading a file from HDFS using spark(scala). A HDFS  block size  is 64 MB.

Assume , the size of HDFS file is 130 MB.

I would like to know how many partitions are created in base RDD

```
scala> val distFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://user/cloudera/data.txt")
```

Is it true that no. of partitions are decided based on block size?

In the above case the no. of partitions is 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.bigsynapse.com/spark-input-output) is a good article that describes the partition computation logic for input.

The HDFS block size is the maximum **size** of a partition. So in your example the minimum **number** of partitions will be 3.

```
partitions = ceiling(input size/block size)
```

You can further increase the number of partitions by passing that as a parameter to `sc.textFile` as in `sc.textFile(inputPath,numPartitions)`

Also another setting `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize` plays a role. You can set it to increase the size of partitions (and reduce the number of partitions). So if you set `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize` to say `130MB` then you will only get 1 partition.

Answer (score 1):

you can run and check number of partitions

> distFile.partitions.size